# Style Django Form Field

Tags: python, django

I have a form which has one ChoiceField. I want to add 'form-control' class to this field.What i am doing is

```
delivery_type = ChoiceField(choices=Student.DELIVERY_CHOICES, widget=Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

But I am getting this error

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'
```

Here is my models.py file:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    DELIVERY_CHOICES = (
        ('Normal', 'Normal (7 working days) (100 BDT Per Semester)'),
        ('Urgent', 'Urgent (3 working days) (200 BDT Per Semester)'),
    )

    delivery_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=DELIVERY_CHOICES)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a better method for you if you want to add `form-control` to all forms:
add this to the template page you want to use

```
<script>
        $('input[type=file]').addClass('form-control');
        $('input[type=number]').addClass('form-control');
        $('input[type=text]').addClass('form-control');
        $('input[type=email]').addClass('form-control');
        $('select').addClass('form-control');
    </script>
```